# webapp2 gettext to work with google cloud endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, internationalization, webapp2

```
from webapp2_extras.i18n import gettext as _
...
_("something")
```

I have some code in my api to call shared function which webapp2 application uses. It uses gettext to translate string, however; when called from Google Cloud Endpoints, I get

```
AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.
```

this applies the same for calling webapp2.uri_for function as well because there's no request global variable set when called from google cloud endpoints. I tried to search for solution, but couldn't unless I modify the actual library.